# Watchman not found in docker, but react-native succeeds building the bundle

Tags: android, docker, react-native, gitlab

I am building a react-native android app in gitlab-ci using the [reactnativecommunity/react-native-android](https://github.com/react-native-community/docker-android/blob/master/Dockerfile) docker image. If i understood correctly, react-native needs `watchman` in order to build the bundle.

But I noticed that `watchman` is not installed on the docker image and I don't install it in the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Also, when I add `which watchman` or `watchman watch-del-all` to the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it returns `watchman: command not found`.

But how is react-native then able to build the bundle?

Answer (score 1):

in the yml script you have to install watchman.
Following are the steps to follow for the same

```
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes autoconf automake build-essential
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes python-dev libtool pkg-config libssl-dev
  - git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
  - cd watchman
  - git checkout v4.9.0
  - ./autogen.sh
  - ./configure --enable-lenient
  - make
  - make install
  - cd ..
  - watchman --version
```